# Pull signal to GND in 3.3V circuit, best way to do it?

Tags: esp32

I want to pull down a signal (5V logic) via my ESP32 (3.3V logic) to logic low. If the GPIO output is set to logic high, the signal should be set to logic low. If the GPIO of my ESP is set to low, the signal should be untouched.

What is the best way to do it?

Is pulling down a signal-line to GND safe, or is there a better way to do it? Because it's a short circuit, isn't it?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWiiAB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Just FYI: I don't know much about the signal. I just know, that its 5 V logic. I don't know the circuit behind the signal.

Comment: Yes, a MOSFET/BJT-based inverters would work. But where does the SIGNAL come from? If it's coming from a low-impedance source with no short-circuit protection then pulling it down directly may damage it. It should have a pull-up so that you can safely pull it down.

Comment: Conversely if the existing signal has a push-pull driver, then what you'd be looking for would be an "AND" gate in a technology such that it could accept a 3v3 input while operating on 5 volts.

Comment: @AlexanderMaier if you don't know the nature of the signal, then you don't know if you can pull it down.  Why do you even want to?   What will consume the signal after you have modified it?  Is it something distinct from the source such that you can cut the signal and insert something?  Without knowledge it's risky to proceed, though you could try an experiment such as seeing how the measured voltage on the signal changes if you place a 1K resistor between it and ground.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've to correct and to add some information. Its a button from a touch pad which I want to "press" via my ESP. I've measured the signal with my oszilloscope and I could see, that grounding the signal means "button is pressed". And yes, I can insert something between source and destination. I already did this and grounded the signal, which worked fine. I just want to know if there is a better solution (adding a resistor or something...).

Comment: Typically a "touch" pad would use some kind of fancy detection and if that is the case this might be a bad idea.  Is this an actually "switch contact"?  If so then you can probably use an FET as drawn.  Tracing back the origin of the signal would make sense.  Also beware that if there are more than a few keys there might be a scanned matrix which could complicate things substantially.

Comment: Yes, its a switch contact. As I mentioned, I already grounded the signal and everything worked fine. I just want to check if there is a better solution.

Comment: If the pushbutton connects the signal pin to ground, then it is OK for the transistor to connect the signal pin to ground too, no difference.

Answer (score 1):

What you’ve shown is fine. The BSS138 has a Vgs threshold of 0.8 to 1.5V, so it will be solidly turned on by your 3.3V GPIO. You could also use the 2N7002.

The FET has an Rds(on) figure of about 2.5 ohms when Vgs is 3V. If it’s dead-shorted to 5V it could see as much as 500mA of current and dissipate as much as 2.5W. If you expect that might be a possibility then consider adding a series resistor of appropriate wattage to limit the current.

Answer (score 0):

If you've been told to pull a logic signal to ground you can expect the voltage to be 5V or less and the current to be less than 10mA

the BSS138 mosfet in  your schematic has no performance figures in the datasheet for less than 4.5V gate drive, so is not a good choice. RK7002BM might be a better choice.

Comment: It has a set of Idss vs. Vgs curves in the datasheet, so it’s most certainly specified. See Figure 1 in the On semi datasheet.